# Searching for keys in a S3 bucket with prefix, suffix or regex?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket that contains a million objects, each object keys are quite different from each other and nothing standard at all.

I want to know if there's a way to search for specific key patterns and return those objects using the Amazon S3 SDK for Java?

For example, can I search for the keys using

- Prefix
- Suffix
- or Regex

What are the possible ways to search for keys with S3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `ListObjects()` with a given **Prefix**. Amazon S3 does not support listing via suffix or regex.

The Prefix includes the full path of the object, so an object with a Key of `2020/06/10/foo.txt` could be found with a prefix of `2020/06/10/`, but not a prefix of `foo`.

The Java command is: [`ListObjects()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#listObjectsV2-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

See also: [Performing Operations on Amazon S3 Objects - AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#list-objects)

With millions of objects, it could be quite slow to list your objects (even with a Prefix) since each API call will return a maximum of 1000 objects.

Alternatively you might want to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file containing a list of all objects.

Comment: Btw, is it possible to have an atomic transaction with S3? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442140/implementing-atomic-operation-with-s3-at-application-level

Comment: @quarks No, each API call to Amazon S3 is independent. There is no concept of "transactions".